# Oracle compatibility setting to make it behave like previous version?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, compatibility

I am using Oracle SQL Developer and my database is on 12c.
Some of my clients are on 11g.

Some entity names that I can create with no errors locally are too long when the client applies my scripts.

Is there a way to change my 12c so that it follows 11g rules?

Comment: You may use [`COMPATIBLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/COMPATIBLE.html#GUID-6C57EE11-BD06-4BB8-A0F7-D6CDDD086FA9) parameter to 11.*, but this parameter cannot be downgraded

Answer (score 0):

There's that [database compatibility](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/upgrd/what-is-oracle-database-compatibility.html#GUID-A2E90F08-BC9F-4688-A9D0-4A948DD3F7A9) thing you can set. This document is about 19c, but the same goes for 12c. It says:

> The compatible parameter must be at least 3 decimal numbers, separated
> by periods.
>
> ```
> SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET COMPATIBLE = '12.1.0.2' SCOPE=SPFILE;
> ```
>
> Oracle recommends that you only raise the COMPATIBLE parameter after
> you have thoroughly tested the upgraded database.
>
> After you increase the COMPATIBLE parameter, you cannot downgrade the
> database.
>
> Caution:
>
> If you are upgrading from Oracle Database release 11.2, then you must
> set the compatible value to at least 11.2.0. You must do this at the
> time of the upgrade. **Do not make this change until you are ready to
> upgrade, because a downgrade back to an earlier compatibility level is
> not possible after you raise the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter
> value**.

So, if you already set it to 12.x, you can't downgrade it to 11.x any more.

Comment: Yes I saw that already, but it doesn't help me (as you also concluded).  I was told such a thing was possible, so I thought it must be some other setting.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask people who told you that it was possible, then.